Splash screen with 2 logos
I am trying to create a splash screen with 2 logos, one on the sender and one as a footer. But I didn't get such type of implementation in MAUI. Is there any way to do it on MAUI?
So I tried platform level integration like below for android.
Created splash_screen.xml under Platforms/Android/Resources/layout folder.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/icon1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon2" />
</RelativeLayout>

Added icon1 and icone2 under Platforms/Android/Resources/drawable folder.
Added theme on AndroidManifest file under application tag.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application 
        android:allowBackup="true" 
        android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" 
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" 
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest> 

Added styles.xml file under Platforms/Android/Resources/values folder and added below code.
<resources>
    <!-- Splash screen theme -->
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@layout/splash_screen</item>
    </style>
</resources>

Finally on the MainActivity added below code:
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the custom splash screen layout
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.splash_screen);
    }
}

While running I getting the below exception:
Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'No view found for id 0x7f08014b (com.companyname.marianconsecration:id/navigationlayout_content) for fragment NavigationRootManager_ElementBasedFragment{f1d86d4} (a90f9cb5-b73f-4ac2-9767-c8bb9b057cb7 id=0x7f08014b)'



There is a similar example that  you can refer to this splash.

@liyu The suggested thread is for Xamarin Forms, I am looking for MAUI.

I found the complete solution and it worked. You can use @drawable/icon1
@drawable/icon2 to resolve the issue. These are all scenarios in Android 12.

Here is my solution, maui .net 8.0 targets android 14.0. and android used the Splash Screen since version 12.0. And according to the official document, the Splash Screen api can put two image: appicon and brand image.
Here's where you can store your two images.
Platforms/Android/Resources/drawable/icon1.jpg
Platforms/Android/Resources/drawable/icon2.jpg
Platforms/Android/MainActivity.cs
 [Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
 public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
 {
    
 }


Platforms/Android/Resources/values/styles.xml
<resources>
      
      <style name="Maui.SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            
            <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/icon1</item>
            <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBrandingImage">@drawable/icon2</item>
            
      </style>
      
</resources>

